# Not able to pass an intent String from an Activity

Tags: android, firebase

I am working on an Android application, where there are 2 types of users. I show them different components of the same Home screen view. So I pass an intent String value named "userType" to filter out what to display. When I login/ Sign Up for the first time into the application, the Home screen works fine and the intent value is not null

I also have another Splash activity, where I check whether the user is already logged in or not. If the user is logged in, I redirect the user directly to the home screen. This time the intent value is showing a Null pointer. I am using Firebase database for the same.

Here is what I have tried to work so far.

Posting the necessary code used for the same.

**SignUpActivity.java**

```
private void writeUserProfile() {

    showProgressDialog("Saving...");
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String fullName = intent.getStringExtra("fullName");
    String userEmailAddress = intent.getStringExtra("emailAddress");
    String userType = intent.getStringExtra("userType");

    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String dateOfBirth = dateofBirthTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String securityAnswer = securityAnswerTextInputEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!validateForm(phoneNumber, dateOfBirth, securityAnswer)) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        return;
    }

    if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")){
        hideProgressDialog();
        Toast.makeText(this, "User details saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent guardianIntent = new Intent(ContactDetailsActivity.this, AddGuardianActivity.class);
//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("fullName", fullName);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("userEmailAddress", userEmailAddress);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("dateofBirth", dateOfBirth);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("userType", userType);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("securityAnswer", securityAnswer);
            guardianIntent.putExtra("securityQuestion", securityQuestion);
            startActivity(guardianIntent);
//        finish();
        }else{
            databaseReference.child("fullName").setValue(fullName);
            databaseReference.child("phoneNumber").setValue(phoneNumber);
            databaseReference.child("dateOfBirth").setValue(dateOfBirth);
            databaseReference.child("securityAnswer").setValue(securityAnswer);
            databaseReference.child("securityQuestion").setValue(securityQuestion);
            databaseReference.child("userType").setValue(userType);

            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Profile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ContactDetailsActivity.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    if(profile != null) {
                        editor.putString(Preferences.NAME, profile.getFullName());
                        editor.putString(Preferences.EMAIL, profile.getEmail());
                    }
                    editor.putString(Preferences.USERID, getUid());
                    editor.apply();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            hideProgressDialog();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(ContactDetailsActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            mainMenuIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mainMenuIntent.putExtra("userType", userType);
            startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
            finish();
        }


    }
```

And in the main menu, I filter the navigationDrawer components based on the userType like this.

MainMenuActivity.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    userType = intent.getStringExtra("userType");


    Fragment home_fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userType", userType);
    home_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, home_fragment);
    transaction.commit();

    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if (getUid() != null) {
        String userId = getUid();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

    } else {
        onAuthFailure();
    }

    final PrimaryDrawerItem home = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Home").withIdentifier(1).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_home);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem profile = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Profile").withIdentifier(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem gallery = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Gallery").withIdentifier(3).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_perm_media_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem recognition = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Recognition").withIdentifier(4).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_face);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem maps = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Maps").withIdentifier(5).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_place_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem tagAndLocate = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Tag & Locate").withIdentifier(6).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem gamesAndPuzzle = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Games & Puzzles").withIdentifier(7).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_casino_black_24dp);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem backup = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Backup").withIdentifier(8).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_save);
    final PrimaryDrawerItem logout = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Logout").withIdentifier(9).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_sign_out);

    DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
        }
    });

    String name = preferences.getString(Preferences.NAME, "");
    String email = preferences.getString(Preferences.EMAIL, "");
    final ProfileDrawerItem userProfile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(name).withEmail(email).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_white_24dp);

    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            .addProfiles(userProfile)
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

    if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")) {
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(home)
                .addDrawerItems(profile)
                .addDrawerItems(gallery)
                .addDrawerItems(recognition)
                .addDrawerItems(maps)
                .addDrawerItems(tagAndLocate)
                .addDrawerItems(gamesAndPuzzle)
                .addDrawerItems(backup)
                .addDrawerItems(new DividerDrawerItem())
                .addDrawerItems(logout)
                .buildForFragment();

        result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                int drawItemId = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                Intent intent;
                Fragment fragment;
                switch (drawItemId) {

                    case 1:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("userType", userType);
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        gaFragmentStack.add(home);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(profile);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(gallery);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new RecognitionFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(recognition);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new MapsFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(maps);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        fragment = new TagLocateFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(tagAndLocate);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        fragment = new GamesPuzzlesFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(gamesAndPuzzle);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        fragment = new BackupFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(backup);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                }
                if (drawItemId == 9) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("userType", userType);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }else{
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(home)
                .addDrawerItems(profile)
                .addDrawerItems(maps)
                .addDrawerItems(backup)
                .addDrawerItems(new DividerDrawerItem())
                .addDrawerItems(logout)
                .buildForFragment();

        result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                int drawItemId = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                Intent intent;
                Fragment fragment;
                switch (drawItemId) {

                    case 1:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("userType", userType);
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        gaFragmentStack.add(home);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(profile);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new MapsFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(maps);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        fragment = new BackupFragment();
                        gaFragmentStack.add(backup);
                        break;
                    default:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                }
                if (drawItemId == 9) {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_gaFragments, fragment);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("userType", userType);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.commit();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Splash screen I was talking about initially

**SplashActivity.java**

```
package com.project.group.projectga.activities;
```

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.project.group.projectga.R;

public class SplashActivity extends CoreActivity {

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    if (getUid() != null) {
        final String userId = getUid();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

        Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                        Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Intent splashScreenIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SplashScreen.class);
                        startActivity(splashScreenIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread.start();
    }
}
```

}

In this case, when the getCurrentUser is not null, I redirect the user to the MainMenuActivity. This line of code in MainMenuActivity shows error, when it is not first time SignUp/Login

```
 ->>>> if(userType.equalsIgnoreCase("Standard")) {
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
```

I don't know how do I pass the userType from the SplashActivity. Please help!

Comment: @IbrahimAli - I know why there is null pointer! I am asking you how do I pass the userType from the SplashActivity?

Comment: The title and body do not really match up with this intended question, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending user type in intent data, from SplashActivity

```
Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
```

you should send user data in that like below,

```
Intent mainMenuIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, 
mainMenuIntent.putExtra("userType", [user type]);
MainMenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(mainMenuIntent);
```

Comment: I find it hard to figure out how to get the userType that is stored in Firebase in SplashActivity, so I can pass it through the intent! Could you help me?

Comment: For getting data from firebase refer this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: Thanks a lot! Figured out how to get the data and was able to pass the userType successfully

Answer (score 0):

I recomand you using this code to get the data back in the second activity.

```
String userType = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("userType");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Splash Activity is my first Activity, and the job of this activity is to check whether the user is already logged in or not. So I can't get data back in this activity. I have to get the database reference and get the userType from there!